# MySQL getting data from 3 tables which are connected by mapping tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following database example:

[image: database scheme]

The example is pretty much self-explanatory: There are lessons held by teachers at defined time periods (time_start, time_end) each time period -> lesson connection has its own max_students number.

I know want to list all lessons with all information of the 3 tables (and the max_students). I would do it like that (I heard, that joining table like that is the fastest way):

```
SELECT * FROM lesson, teacher, time, teacher_has_lesson, time_has_lesson
WHERE lesson.lesson_id = teacher_has_lesson.lesson_lesson_id
AND teacher.teacher_id = teacher_has_lesson.teacher_teacher_id
AND lesson.lesson_id = time_has_lesson.lesson_lesson_id
AND time.time_id = time_has_lesson.time_time_id
```

1.) Is this a good solution if you just want to join 3 tables or are there better ones?

2.) This SQL call will get me only lessons, that have a teacher and a time. I also want to display lessons, that are in the database, but dont have a teacher or time yet. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an alternative way of writing this using `join` syntax. What you have is equivalent to an `inner join`, where you only see rows where there are matches:

```
select
    *
from
    lesson l
        inner join
    teacher_has_lesson tl
        on l.lession_id = tl.lesson_lesson_id
        inner join
    teacher t
        on tl.teacher_teacher_id = t.teacher_d
        inner join
    time_has_lesson tml
        on l.lesson_id = tml.lesson_lesson_id
        inner join
    time tm
        on tml.time_time_id = tm.time_ud
```

There's another type of join called `outer join`, where all the rows from one table are shown, and null values supplied if there are no matching values in the other table. It comes in two or three variants. `left outer join` shows all rows from the first table. `right outer join` shows all rows from the second table. `full outer join` shows all rows from both tables. So, for your second query you could use:

```
select
    *
from
    lesson l
        left outer join
    teacher_has_lesson tl
        on l.lession_id = tl.lesson_lesson_id
        left outer join
    teacher t
        on tl.teacher_teacher_id = t.teacher_d
        left outer join
    time_has_lesson tml
        on l.lesson_id = tml.lesson_lesson_id
        left outer join
    time tm
        on tml.time_time_id = tm.time_ud
```